# How to remove a 0 in text field for INT value in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 3.5,WebLogic server in JDeveloper.

Validation part of my .xhtml file is:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Route Id "></h:outputLabel>
   <p:inputText id="rouid" value="#{addcust.c1.routeid}"
      listener="#{addcust.routedata}" title="Click to Select Route" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter route ID" validatorMessage="Id must contain Digits">
<f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="11"/>
</p:inputText>
```

mybean.java:

```
private Integer routeid;
    public void setRouteid(Integer routeid) {
        this.routeid = routeid;
    }

    public Integer getRouteid() {
        return routeid;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `int` field to `Integer`. This will default to `null` unless it is initialized explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for reply.It's Working,But i had a problem with validate messages after changing int to Integer.The growl messages are not showing the validate message i wrote.It Showing like  Regex Pattern is not matched.And what is the difference between int and Integer .

Comment: Integer is a class in java where as int is a primitive type. Integer object have methods that can be used to perform different operations.

Could you please post your validation code?

Comment: Thanks for Replying.The validation code is:            <h:outputLabel value="Route Id "></h:outputLabel>
   <p:inputText id="rouid" value="#{addcust.c1.routeid}"
      listener="#{addcust.routedata}" title="Click to Select Route" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter route ID" validatorMessage="Id must contain Digits">
<f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="11"/>
</p:inputText>.

Comment: Could you please edit the original question to add your bean class and xhtml code?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. If you still have this problem, could you tell me in which case does the error message say "Regex Pattern is not matched"?